# Ajuda escapar caracteres especiais php

Tags: php

Estou tendo dificuldade em salvar caracteres especiais. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde o professor precisa escrever uma observação em um textarea. Estou usando o código abaixo, para salva/atualizar o campo observação:

```
$.ajax({
 url: '<?php echo site_url('accountant/update_planning/'); ?>' + id + 
 '/' + encodeURI(observation) + '/' + status,
  success: function (response)
     {
       buttonSend.innerHTML = 'Salvar';
            $.notify({
                title: '<strong>Sucesso!</strong>',
                message: 'O planejamento foi atualizado com sucesso.'
            }, { type: 'success' });
        },
        error: function (response)
        {
            buttonSend.innerHTML = 'Salvar';
            $.notify({
                title: '<strong>Erro!</strong>',
                message: 'Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o planejamento.'
            }, { type: 'danger' });
        }
    });
```

O problema é o seguinte: Ao usar a função encodeuri, ela não deixa escapar (A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #)

Ao usar a função escape(observation), ela não deixar escapar os acentos.

Então o que eu preciso, é que escape aceite os acentos e o caracteres como (, ! ; / ? :)

Como contornar esse problema?

Comment: Você pode capturar os dados usando base64encode, base64decode... tem isso em [javascript](https://www.devpleno.com/como-converter-uma-string-em-base64-em-javascript-navegador-e-nodejs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você usou a função errada, `encondeURI` é para escapar em URI "inteiras", exemplo:

```js
var uri = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/?q=[javascript] á é ? #teste a b c ó ú';
var resultado = encodeURI(uri);
console.log(resultado);
```

Para usar em strings "normais" use o `encodeURIComponent` assim:

```
url: '<?php echo site_url('accountant/update_planning/'); ?>' + id + 
'/' + encodeURIComponent(observation) + '/' + status,
```

Comment: Grato, pela explicação e ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Vou fazer um exemplo que utiliza base64encode/base64decode ok:

```
var Base64 = {


    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",


    encode: function(input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output + this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },


    decode: function(input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    _utf8_encode: function(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    _utf8_decode: function(utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0, c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0, c = 0;

        while (i < utftext.length) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            } else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            } else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}
```

Faça o encode:

```
var observation = Base64.encode(observation);
```

Ficaria assim:

```
$.ajax({
 url: '<?php echo site_url('accountant/update_planning/'); ?>' + id + 
 '/' +  observation + '/' + status,
  success: function (response)
     {
       buttonSend.innerHTML = 'Salvar';
            $.notify({
                title: '<strong>Sucesso!</strong>',
                message: 'O planejamento foi atualizado com sucesso.'
            }, { type: 'success' });
        },
        error: function (response)
        {
            buttonSend.innerHTML = 'Salvar';
            $.notify({
                title: '<strong>Erro!</strong>',
                message: 'Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o planejamento.'
            }, { type: 'danger' });
        }
    });
```

No lado servidor não sei como você está capturando, porque você não acrescentou na pergunta, então vou simular que fosse assim:

```
$observation = base64_decode($_POST['observation']);
```

Answer (score -4):

ola amigo pode ser problema no momento da criação do banco verifica como esta o encoding UTF-8 geralmente e o padrão, se estiver enviando em outro formato que não condiz com o do banco  pode ocorre este erro.
por exemplo os browser atuais só enviam em UTF-8...

Comment: "os browser atuais só enviam em UTF-8", como assim? Qual a fonte desta informação?

Comment: Anderson Carlos talvez tenha expressado mal, geralmente get/post os browser trata de enviar ultilizando charset ISO-8859-1, tem que ter esta observação pra ñ ter conflitos no lado do servidor.. não entendi foi "Quando você tiver reputação suficiente, você vai poder deixar comentários em qualquer post" se faz necessário ter quantos pontos pra ajudar o amigo em duvida? o  outro amigo colocou "No lado servidor não sei como você está capturando, porque você não acrescentou na pergunta, então vou simular que fosse assim" foi esta a minha pergunta que poderia ser de solução também!!